# selecting multiple sheets in the form listbox and merge selected to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Currently i am able to select multiple sheets in the list box however i am not able to merge the selected sheets into a new sheet. Can anyone please help me with this. And here is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim wrk As Workbook
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim colCount As Integer

  Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook

  For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then


Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
Set sht = ListBox1.List(i)

For Each sht In ListBox1
If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
Exit For
End If

Set Rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count).Value = Rng.Value
Next sht
trg.Columns.AutoFit

      End If
  Next i

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

For n = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
With ListBox1
    .AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name
End With
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: There are a few issues, but you are not defining colCount for one.

Comment: SJR is correct. Try changing (, colCount)) to (, 10))  and test to see if it copies the first 10 columns and every row of each sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing somewhat as I don't know the value of colCount for one thing

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wrk As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim trg As Worksheet

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook
colCount = 4
Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        Set sht = Sheets(ListBox1.List(i))
        With sht
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
        End With
        trg.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count).Value = Rng.Value
        trg.Columns.AutoFit
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```